# How can I set timeouts for resource.StateChangeConf from terraform-sdk-go?

Tags: terraform

Some context: I'm currently writing a provider and I've got the following piece of code:

```golang
stateConf := &resource.StateChangeConf{
    Pending:      []string{IN_PROGRESS},
    Target:       []string{DONE},
    Refresh:      fooRefresh(ctx, c, barId, d.Id()),
    Timeout:      120 * time.Minute,
    ...
    PollInterval: 1 * time.Minute,
    MinTimeout:   120 * time.Second,
}

_, err = stateConf.WaitForStateContext(ctx)
```

I'm also using HashiCorp's terraform [sdk](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk) and here's the [doc](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/main/helper/resource/state.go#L24) about `StateChangeConf` but the basic idea is that even though my `PollInterval` is set to 1 minute it seems like TF ignores that value and polls every 10 seconds anyway:

```
foo_resource.bar-name: Creating...
foo_resource.bar-name: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
foo_resource.bar-name: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
foo_resource.bar-name: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
foo_resource.bar-name: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
foo_resource.bar-name: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
foo_resource.bar-name: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
```

and it timed out after 1 minute (instead of 120 minutes that I set for `resource.StateChangeConf` as well), is there a way to debug it or something? I'm using `terraform v0.15.3` if it helps at all.

Comment: Since you are using v0.15 of terraform, these are some debugging steps provided by terraform doc while doing the provider development - https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/debugging.html. You can enable the debug mode like mentioned over here - https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/debugging.html#enabling-debugging-in-a-provider